# Possible to prefix string to one-liner output?

Tags: perl

If I do

```
perl -nE'say for m|fullImageLink.+?<a href="(.+?)"|g' tmp
```

then I get

```
/images/9/92/233-Menu.jpg
```

Would it be possible to prefix the output with `example.com/`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
perl -nE'say q{example.com}, $_ for m|fullImageLink.+?<a href="(.+?)"|g' tmp
```

Will break horribly if there is a domain name already present.